# React-Native: Animate component to slide in on Top of other Component

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation

I'm currently working on a react-native app to play videos. Now i want to have a component, that slides in on top of another component when this on is clicked - like a dropdown menu, but to the top.

I've figured out how to do the animation, but the problem is, the component that is then covered by the new component is also touchable. Now I want that the newly slid in component gets the touch event, since it should be possible to select things in it, but actually only the component below gets the touches. I've tried adding zIndex to the style but i cannot figure out why this is not possible.

Here is the basic test code for the component handling this behaviour, any help is really appreciated. Currently all that should be happening, is that the second touchableopacity should slide in, and when pressed slide out again:

```
export default class ExtendedControlsComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}

}

componentDidMount() {

}

render() {
    return (
        <Animated.View
            onLayout={(event) => {
                let {height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                (!this.state.viewHeight) && this.setState({
                    viewHeight : new Animated.Value(height),
                    viewPosition: new Animated.Value(height),
                    height: height,
                })
            }}
            style={[customStyles.extendedControlsView, this.state.viewHeight && {height: this.state.viewHeight}]}>


                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.animate.bind(this)}
                    style={[{height: '100%'}]}

                >
                    <Text>
                        test
                    </Text>

                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.animate.bind(this)}
                    style={[{
                        position:'absolute',
                        backgroundColor: constants.colors.green,
                        height:0,
                        left:0,
                        width:'100%',
                        transform: [{'translate':[0,0,1]}]
                    }, this.state.viewPosition && {height:2*this.state.height, top:this.state.viewPosition}]}
                    >
                    <Text>
                        test2
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
        </Animated.View>
    )
}

async animate() {
    if(this.state.viewPosition._value < this.state.height) {
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.viewPosition,
            {
                toValue: this.state.height,
                //easing: Easing.elastic(),
                duration: 500,

            }
        ).start()
    } else {
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.viewPosition,
            {
                toValue: -2*this.state.height,
                easing: Easing.elastic(),
                duration: 500,

            }
        ).start()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use modal for this. https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal

Comment: I already tried using Modal, but Modal always takes up the entrie screen, even if the content is smaller, making the visible background no longer touchable - or at least i have found no way to do it. I want to still propagate touches that are outside the overlay to the background.

Comment: if you could create a snack, we could work on it together. It's hard for me to reproduce this and get the result you want.